# How to do Python , PostgreSQL integration?

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to call PostgreSQL queries and return results for python APIs?
Basically , do a python and PostgreSQL integration/Connectivity.
So, for specific Python API /calls want to execute the queries n return result.

Also, want to achieve  abstraction of PostgreSQL DB.

Thanks.

Comment: [SQLAlchemy - The Python SQL Toolkit and Object Relational Mapper](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to klin's comment:

[psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2) - 
This is the most popular psql adapter for python. It was build to address heavy concurrency issues with psql database usage. Several extensions are available for added functionality with the DB API.

[asyncpg](http://magic.io/blog/asyncpg-1m-rows-from-postgres-to-python/) - 
More recent psql adapter which seeks to address shortfalls in functionality and performance that exist with psycopg2. Doubles the speed of psycopg's text based data exchange protocol by using binary I/O (which adds generic support for container types). A Major plus is that it has zero dependencies. No personal experience with this adapter but will test soon.